# When will IPv4 addresses run out?

Tags: ipv6, ipv4

From years I am hearing that soon IPv4 address will run out. When will it happen? When will we see IPv6 only application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's scheduled for December 21, 2012.

Comment: What coincidence! Same day I booked my end of the world cruise :)

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_address_exhaustion) is your friend

FWIW use of NAT can extend the life of IP4 for much longer IMHO